# How to let Cypress return custom errors or messages

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm looking for a way to create a custom message instead of the standard messages. What I have is this piece of code (scrambled a bit):

```
Cypress.Commands.add('authenticate', {prevSubject: 'optional'}, (_, fixture) => {
  return cy.fixture(fixture).then(credentials => {
    cy
      .apiRequest('scrambled/url/here', {
        method: 'post',
        authorizationMethod: 'Basic',
        token: apiOauthSecret,
        data: credentials
      })
      .then(resp => {
        expect(resp.status)
          .to
          .eq(201, 'Unable to authenticate, login failed')
        storeTokenInSession(resp.body)
      })
  })
})
```

That code results in a error like this:

[image]

If I fix the code so the result is okay the result looks like this:

[image]

As you see the message should be displayed if the eq() fails instead of when the eq() succeeds.

I want to show the message only if the check fails, but I also want the test to break and stop.

Do you people have any idea how to get this working? I already looked into using cy.log() and the solution shown here.

Answer (score 5):

No need for `Cypress.log()`.

```js
if (resp.status !== 201) {
  expect(resp.status, 'Unable to authenticate, login failed').to.eq(201)
}
```

If it's good, it moves on. Else it fails with the error message.

An advantage of this is you don't get a grey error message, you get it in red instead.

If you also want the success case just add:

```js
else {
  expect(resp.status, 'Able to authenticate, login succeeded').to.eq(201)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Cypress.log](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-log.html#Syntax) for that:

```js
if (resp.status !== 201) {
  Cypress.log({
    name: 'Authentication',
    message: 'failed'
  })
}
expect(resp).its('status').eq(201)
```

Comment: that's the same result as I get wit the .eq(201, 'Unable to authenticate, login failed'). The message is only shown if the test doesn't break, but I want it the other way around: only show the message if the assertion does fail.

Comment: Ok, I've inverted the logic

Comment: Guess I wasn't clear enough. I figured that inverting the logic would work. But my problem then is that the test continues to run. So what I want is:

1. Test fails

2. "This is the custom error"
3. The test does not continue

And what I get with the given solution is:
1. Test fails

2. Custom error is shown"

3. The test continues and does NOT break.

Comment: Yes, so you simply add your assertion after

Comment: Ah, I could have thought of that... But it works! Thx for the support

Comment: How would you modify for the should assertions? passing the message parameter does not work {message: 'test' }

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in this case is to simply throw an error. To me it looks like the sample code in the question is abusing `expect`, based on the assumption that you're not actually writing a test case here, but a function to use *in the course* of a test. Here is my proposed solution:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('authenticate', {prevSubject: 'optional'}, (_, fixture) => {
  return cy.fixture(fixture).then(credentials => {
    cy
      .apiRequest('scrambled/url/here', {
        method: 'post',
        authorizationMethod: 'Basic',
        token: apiOauthSecret,
        data: credentials
      })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status !== 201) {
          throw new Error('Unable to authenticate, login failed')
        }

        storeTokenInSession(resp.body)
      })
  })
})
```

This would cause a test that uses that command to fail if this `authenticate` function did not get a `201` response, and you would get (what I would consider to be) a helpful message in the Cypress UI.

I feel like a root problem here and in some of the other responses is that the testing functionality (`expect`, again) is being abused. While in some sense you are "testing" the response status, what I believe is trying to be achieved here is not a "test" in the way that Cypress is concerned.